# Superscripts and subscripts in tensors - interpretation as a matrix operation?

Tags: notation, tensors

Consider the equation
$$u_k = t_i U_i^k$$

I am told that subscripts represent covectors (row vectors) and superscripts represent column vectors. My intuitive interpretation of the above equation as a matrix multiplication fails since  $(1 \times n) \ne (1  \times m) \times (n \times m)$, where $n$ is the range of $k$ and $m$ is the range of $i$.

I am assuming that $U_i^k$ must instead represent an $m \times n$ matrix, but would this not contradict the rule of superscripts representing the column index? Is there a rule in tensor notation which covers this, or did the author of equation make a mistake and should write $U_k^i$?

Comment: $u_k = t_i U_i^k$ is interpreted as the sum $\displaystyle\Sigma_i t_i U_i^k$ and only the index $k$ is free.

Comment: It's really not even proper notation...the $k$'s are in different sub and superscript positions

Comment: So would I be correct to say that the author of that equation was using bad notation and it should be $u_k=t_i U_k^i = \Sigma_i t_i U_k^i$, because $\Sigma_i t_i U_i^k = u^k$?

Comment: Assuming $u_k$ to be the covariant components of a vector $u$, you would have $u_k = U_{k}^i t_i$. The sum involves one subscript and one superscript. $U_{k}^i$ are the components of the linear map $U$. In matrix form, you could think of this as $\{u_k\} = [U_{ki}]\{t_i\}$, where the {t} and {u} are column-vectors.